# How to give an input "submit"-type a text-value but also a PHP id to identify the value by POST-request to delete a database entry?

Tags: php, forms

I guess the title got complicated, I got a Userlist where a table shows users and it should get a option to delete the user. So I requested all users from the database, and placed them in a table, but a delete-button should be next to every user, to delete it. I would like to call the button-text "delete" but to gain the ID of the user, I thought of giving the value-attribute the database-id to send that value to the $_POST var.

This is what I made so far:

```
if ($con) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ";
                    $ergebnis = $con->query($sql);
                    while ($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        echo "<table>
                            <tr><td><h4> User: " . $zeile["user"] . "</h4></td></tr>
                            <tr><td> <form action='admin.php' method='post'> <input type='submit' name='delete' value='" . $zeile["id"] . "'></td></tr>   </form> 
                        </table>";
                    }
                }
```

The list as an image:

[image]

So every user has it's ID as an value, have a $_POST varaiable to work with. But of course, the text shouldn't be the value but something like "delete". Is there an alternative way to do it?

I hope you get my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your form as:

```
<form action='admin.php' method='post'> 
    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete user'>
    <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='" . $zeile["id"] . "'>
</form>
<!-- Also not that first you close `form` and only then - `td-tr` -->
```

On server side you will have user id in `$_POST['user_id']`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it perfectly, and thanks for the </form> correction!